# concatenate variable doesn't work how I want

Tags: bash, variables, awk, character

I need to concatenate two variables and a character

The first variable `$line` is read from a file by `line=$(awk "NR==$i" in_parameters.txt)`.

```
echo $line
2;0.250;0.250;1.520;0.000;0.025;32
```

The second variable is also read from a file

```
extr_out=$(awk "NR==1" "${i}_out.txt")

echo $extr_out
0.249510039979791
```

What I want is create `line2= $line + ";" + $extr_out`

```
echo $line2
2;0.250;0.250;1.520;0.000;0.025;32;0.249510039979791
```

I tried using

```
line2=$line
line2+=";"
echo $line2
;;0.250;0.250;1.520;0.000;0.025;32
```

or

```
line2=$line$extr_out
echo $line2
&nbsp;&nbsp;0.2495100399797910;0.000;0.025;32
```

but the problem is that the value is written at the beginning of the chain and not appended at the end.

I probably do not understand something correctly. Can anybody help me with that? How does bash work with these variables?

Answer (score 3):

Your file `in_parameters.txt` has Windows line endings (CR-LF), so when you extract an entire line with `awk`, the line ends with a carriage return. Hence, when you append something to the end of the line, you are putting it after the carriage return, so it overwrites the text at the beginning of the line.

Use `dos2unix` to remove the CRs, and you should be fine. (You might want to check your other data files as well.)

Comment: Thank you very much! I wasn' aware of that! It works now! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate like this?

```
$ line='2;0.250;0.250;1.520;0.000;0.025;32'
$ extr_out='0.249510039979791'
$ line2=$(echo "$line;$extr_out")
$ echo "$line2"
2;0.250;0.250;1.520;0.000;0.025;32;0.249510039979791
```

Comment: perfect, that helped! I can continue my stuff.Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

several ways

Using sed

```
echo "$(sed -n "${i}p" in_parameters.txt);$(head -1 ${i}_out.txt)"
echo "$(sed -n "${i}p" in_parameters.txt);$(sed -n "1p" ${i}_out.txt)"
```

Using awk

```
awk -v s=$i 'NR==FNR{if (FNR==s) printf $0 ";";next} {if (FNR==1) print}' in_parameters.txt ${i}_out.txt
```

Of course, you can use your exist code to merge them as @jaypal singh shows.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the variables, but the `;` must be escaped as it would otherwise signify a new line in the script.

```
line2=$line\;$extr_out
```

Or you could use curly braces to separate the variable name from `;` and use quotes.

```
line2="${line};$extr_out"
```